# Sum column dynamically

Tags: excel

Having `A1+C1` and `B1+D1` in two cells how can I dynamically set up a formula to catch if some column is added.
Let's say the user adds two columns in the middle. I should have `A1+C1+E1` and `B1+D1+F1`.

I thought it would have been automatic but it is not.

Comment: If they only add one column?

Comment: Are the columns in between empty? And are the values text or numeric or mixture? And does it always start at column A?

Comment: As per your comments, their doestn't seems to be any defined logic that can be used to have the sum, (neither even/odd nor the sum()) but maybe the sum can be linked with the headers, it would be helpful if you can take a screenshot of your sheet and paste it here.

Comment: Hi usmanhaq, you are correct. All the columns follow the same logic H1,P3,L1,K2,U9 these are codes repeated for each customer so the sheet looks like:  H1,P3,L1,K2,U9,H1,P3,L1,K2,U9,H1,P3,L1,K2,U9,H1,P3,L1,K2,U9...in teh second row, the first is the name of the customer. I need to sum these five code by quantity (the quanity is in the third row).

Comment: Still i would say that give a screenshot or a sample of your sheet, if your data is sensitive you can create some random figures, like customer 1 customer 2..  What i have understood with your comment may not be the actual case so it is better to be confirmed, and also let me know what would happen with these headers after a column is inserted and why it is inserted. and another thing is if you want to address someone in comments you have to write his name with @ like @Diegoctn

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
=A1+C1
```

By:

```
=SUM(A1:C1) - B1
```

In case you want to check if the column number is divisble by three, you can use following formula:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(A1);3)=0;A1;0) // I've put the values from 1 to 10 in A1-J1
                              // and I've dragged this formula from A2 to J2, 
                              // the values were 0,0,3,0,0,6,0,0,9,0.
```

Unfortunately I don't have a simple way to sum those values in one easy formula.

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks but my problem is a little bit more complex. I have a cell with A1+D1+G1+J1...until the end and B1+E1+H1+K1...until the end. Now, if a user insert a new set of column I should be able to pick up the change. The range is always +3 columns   A1+(A1+3 columns) D1+ (D1+3 columns) G1+.....no idea how can I achieve that. Is there a formula that can help me?

Comment: @Diegoctn: I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: I know I thank you. As per above comment, I tried to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you always add two columns then `A1+C1` will always be looking at odd number columns and `B1+D1` will always be looking at even numbered columns.

```
{=SUM(IF(ISODD(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)),$A$1:$D$1))}
```

and

```
{=SUM(IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)),$A$1:$D$1))}
```

As long as you insert columns between `A:D` the ranges will extend to accommodate.

**Edit:**
Based on the comment that row 2 contains codes and row 3 contains the figures to add up for each code then this array formula will work:

```
{=SUM(IF($A$2:$J$2="H1",$A$3:$J$3))}
```

*Edit2:* and if I wake up you can even use the non-array and built in formula:
`=SUMIF($A$2:$J$2,"H1",$A$3:$J$3)`

The `H1` text can be changed to another code or to a cell reference containing the code to get the sum of values in row 3 for the specified code.

As an array formula it must be entered using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: Don't forget to mention you're working with array formulas: you don't put the `{` and `}` characters yourself, you just enter the formula (starting with `=` and instead of pressing ENTER, you press CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.